Minizip not working to compress file that has size > 4 GB
My  program uses minizip(zlib- version 1.2.3) to compress an xml file. When the xml file size is greater than 4 GB(in fact
the max value of int 32 - 4294967295) then I find that when I try to extract the compressed file it gave me an unexpected error 0x80004005 (able to extract via 7zip).
I believe the zipping did not work properly.
If I check the size of the xml file then the size =(total bytes in the file) -(max value of int32). Please see the screenshot.
Size of zip file which is what remains after reducing the 4 GB
Now coming to the way the file is being zipped I am using below minizip fnctions with these params. If any of you are aware what is going wrong in the minizip compresiion for large files could you please give me suggestions
int returnVal = zipOpenNewFileInZip4(reinterpret_cast<zipFile>(m_pzipFile),
                                        fileName, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL,
                                        Z_DEFLATED, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, 0,
                                        -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
                    NULL, 0, m_uGeneralflag);//Z_DEFLATED-0,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION=-1,MAX_WBITS=15,DEF_MEM_LEVEL=8,Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY=0

zipWriteInFileInZip(reinterpret_cast<zipFile>(m_pzipFile)// pBuffer, actualBufferSize)===>m-pzipFile void*,pBuffer  of type char*  that is being written to compressed file, actualBufferSize --int value that is size of pBuffer
zipCloseFileInZip(reinterpret_cast<zipFile>(m_pzipFile))

Possible fixes or awreness of problem, how to solve

Are you sure you have 1.2.3? That version didn't have zipOpenNewFileInZip4().

I believe certain functions were added like zipOpenNewFileInZip4 from later versions on to the 1.2.3. I am also trying to find out and get the relevant changes corresponding to the 64 bit functions alone; since our application has dependency on zlib and want whatever finctioning today should remain as is but get the 64 bit related changes alone so that larger files may use the new functions and work without any change to existing ones; would that be possible ?

So what version of zlib are you actually using?

Could you please tell me what is the version I need to integrate which has large file support (assuming its via 64 bit functions)..I see the version here in the code repo as 1.2.3 but as you rightly said it doesnt have functions like zipOpenNewFileInZip4, so I think selectively few changes wer pickep up from later versions

Just get the latest version, 1.3.1.

You are using a 13-year old version of zlib. Get the current version from http://zlib.net/ or https://github.com/madler/zlib (the latter where you yourself had posted this same question!) and compile it. It has a zipOpenNewFileInZip4_64() function.
